# How to setup PHP CodeSniffer + Formartter profile for CakePHP in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cakephp, configuration, conventions, sniffer

I'm trying to use [PHP CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected) + [CakePHP Sniffer](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer) + [Eclipse PHP Tool Integration](http://www.phpsrc.org/eclipse/pti/)

I installed the Eclipse plugin as well as download and install the CakePHP CodeSniffer code on my Eclipse as you can see on the image below.

[image: Eclipse PHP CodeSinffer configuration]

I select the `print PHP output to console` so I can see and error when it's trying to analyze my code

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHP_CodeSniffer_Exception' with message 'Referenced sniff PSR2.Namespaces.NamespaceDeclaration does not exist' in /home/israel/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0_1473617060_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000/php/library/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:814
```

What could be the problem?

In the other hand I want to be able to format my code following the CakePHP Conventions where can I found a `fomatter profile` that match with the CakePHP code conventions.

Thanks

Comment: so did you find any good for formatter profile?

Comment: Nothing! I tried to build my own with Eclipse Formatter, but there there are a lot of things that you can´t do to match the conventions :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had several problem trying to install CodeSniffer and make it run with Eclipse properly.

That was the steps I followed to made it run properly, you will find on this post detailed instructions about how to configure, [How to Eclipse + CodeSniffer + CakePHP Sniff](http://blog.zot24.com/how-to-codesniffer-cakephp-code-with-eclipse/).

---

Go to the preferences menu on `Eclipse` and navigate to...

```
PHP -> PHP Executables -> Add...
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [zot24.com](http://blog.zot24.com/content/images/2014/Feb/configuring_php_homebrew_in_eclipse.png))</sub>

Once we have PHP configured on our Eclipse we have to setup `PEAR` go to...

```
PHP Tools -> Library -> PEAR -> New...
```

And select the `path` where `php55` was installed using `homebrew`, you can run this command to know the path of `php55`

```
brew --prefix php55
```

Then just add at the end of that command

```
.../lib/PHP
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [zot24.com](http://blog.zot24.com/content/images/2014/Feb/codesniffer_cakephp_eclipse_1.png))</sub>

And the last step is select our just configured `PEAR` path a the default library used by our `PHP CodeSniffer`, as you can see on the imagen below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [zot24.com](http://blog.zot24.com/content/images/2014/Feb/codesniffer_cakephp_eclipse_2.png))</sub>

And done! just enjoy a code clean! :)

[image]
<sub>(source: [zot24.com](http://blog.zot24.com/content/images/2014/Feb/codesniffer_cakephp_eclipse_3.png))</sub>